# Suppress black box at end of line

Tags: line-breaking, boxes

Under TeX, when I write a line too long, it prints a fat black box at the end
of the line. 
That is probably a feature, but I dislike it.

How to turn that OFF? Is there a command-line option or something else?

I usually use LaTeX, but I have a complicated file which happens to be plain TeX.

Comment: Don't fight the consequences, eliminate the cause.

Answer (score 15):

Since you are using Plain TeX, the answer is

```
\overfullrule=0pt
```

before the text starts.

Answer (score 8):

I think the `draft` option, as mentioned by Alan, works with LaTeX classes. Try to set `\overfullrule=0pt` in Plain TeX.

See *The TeXBook*.

Comment: I don't think that PDF is legal.

Comment: Indeed, while the [source code of *The TeXBook* is on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook) creating and sharing PDFs from it is not allowed by the copyright holder. A good free alternative is *[TeX for the Impatient](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/impatient/)* (PDF on CTAN or `texdoc impatient`). For `\overfullrule` see page 170 (PDF page 190). @egreg

Comment: @Martin: I didn’t know that. Thanks for your edit :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Fixing the illness directly, not the symptoms

The black boxes usually occur alongside the error:

> Overfull \hbox (3.14159pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 41--42

This usually means that there is too much text being rendered in a single line of the output PDF:

```
|The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy doggie.  |  <-- boundary
|This is the rendered output PDF of a TeX document.|  <-- boundary
|This cannot fit on one line without being squashed.| <-- overfull!
|Unfortunately, if TeX made a break before "being" |  <-- boundary
|and "squashed", it would look weird.              |  <-- boundary
```

One way to fix this is to simply reword the paragraph causing the issue so that TeX can make a line break in a visually pleasing matter. Often, this merely involves removing or adding a few words until the issue disappears:

```
|The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy doggie.  |  <-- boundary
|This is the rendered output PDF of a TeX document.|  <-- boundary
|This can fit on one line without being squashed.  |  <-- FIXED!
|Unfortunately, if TeX made a break before "being" |  <-- boundary
|and "squashed", it would look weird.              |  <-- boundary
```

---

#### Addressing the symptoms instead

Of course, one can change the tolerances, at the cost of looking less aesthetically pleasing. If we set [`\sloppy`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241355/2930), the result might look like:

```
|The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy doggie.  |  <-- boundary
|This is the rendered output PDF of a TeX document.|  <-- boundary
|This cannot fit on one line without being         |  <-- UGLY
|squashed. Unfortunately, if TeX made a break      |  <-- UGLY
|before "being" and "squashed", it would look      |  <-- UGLY
|weird.                                            |  <-- UGLY
```

Instead, if we set [`\overfullrule=0pt`](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/%5Coverfullrule), as described in [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22558/2930), the `Overfull \hbox` error is silently swept under the rug, but our text still goes over the boundary and/or is overly squashed together, as shown in the first example.

Content and presentation are intertwined. Sometimes we must compromise a bit of one for the other.