# Some messy random black boxes in Latex

Tags: errors, pdftex, pdf, boxes

I'm using the online tool shareLatex, when I compile the document I have some random blackbox appears in the right-side of the document. I have no errors in the document. Does anyone knows what is the reason of these black boxes.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you are compiling using the `draft` option. These boxes indicate overfull lines.

Comment: It seems that class option `draft` is set. The black boxes mark lines which are too long. Click the "Logs and output file" button (next to the "Recompile" button) to see the messages regarding overfull boxes.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22556/suppress-black-box-at-end-of-line?rq=1

Comment: @samcarter That was really helpful, thank you. Please post it as an answer so I can choose it. Thank you

Comment: @F505 You're welcome! As we already have similar questions on this site it's better to close as duplicate instead of writing a new answer.